# Using NGRX within Angular Library

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using NGRX within my application. But within my Angular Library I want to join that NGRX module and add to it. However, when I try to call `StoreModule.forRoot()` within the library, I can't. Because I already called it once in the main application.

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
    CompoLoginRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        deps: [HttpClient],
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
      },
    }),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { // This is a problem
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true,
      },
      metaReducers,
    }),
```

Is there a right way to join the NGRX of the main application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using ngrx store module in app module then please add this section in app.moudle.ts

```
import { reducers, metaReducers } from "./reducers";

StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      metaReducers,
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true,
      },
    }),
```

this is the command for generating root store

```
ng generate store AppState --root --module app.module.ts
```

effects also like this in app.module.ts

```
EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
```

if ngrx store module in child module the add like this assets.moudle.ts,

```
import * as fromAssetsStore from "./store/assets.reducer";

StoreModule.forFeature(
  fromAssetsStore.assetsFeatureKey,
  fromAssetsStore.aReducer,
  {
    metaReducers: fromAssetsStore.metaReducers,
  }
),
EffectsModule.forFeature([AssetsEffects]),
```